# How to use where clause in google firebase Realtime Database using React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to delete document where receiver email is test@gmail.com in google firebase realtime database using react native.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
const database = firebase.database();
database.ref(`private-message`).where('receiver','==','test@gmail.com').remove();
```

But I have this error.

```
database.ref("private-message").where is not a function.
```

[database structure like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVMnP.png)

Please help me!!!

Comment: How is `database` object defined?

Comment: Question has edited. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
database.ref(`private-message`).orderByChild('receiver').equalTo(test@gmail.com).remove();
```

Comment: database.ref("private-message").orderByChild('receiver').equalTo('test@gmail.com').remove is not a function

Comment: I have same error.

Comment: Please help me!!